# Instagram curl returns login page

Tags: php, instagram

I trying to use Curl https://www.instagram.com/durov/?__a=1. Browser opens the page. Postman returns data, but when I trying to use php curl - I receive blank page. Anybody know how to fix it?

My code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.instagram.com/durov/?__a=1",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 406fa2df-4649-b3af-1fcb-806d9be8678f"
  ),
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Can you use their API? https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this one liner?

`file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/durov/?__a=1');`

So...

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/durov/?__a=1');

$array = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($array); // Do anything you want with the data
```

Comment: I tried, but it fails too. Seems like Instagram block requests. Can you check it on your website?

Comment: I checked my code and its working perfectly. Maybe you got IP blocked due to too many requests?